# What's the correct way to derive the eq. of a parabola without knowing the conventional values of focus and directrix?

Tags: conic-sections

According to the convention that we are taught in our schools, focus = (a,0) [for a standard parabola] and directrix: x=-a. But is there any way to obtain the equation without knowing these conventions?

I know the basic definition is this: A Parabola is the locus of all points whose distance from a point is equal to their perpendicular distance from a line known as the directrix.

But is it possible to derive the equation from the ground up using just the definition and not making any of the assumptions like I did in the first line?

P.S - If you have the link to the derivation or any article that is related to this, please do send it!

Thankyou so much!

Comment: In Mathematics there is rarely THE correct way of doing anything. Most times there is more than one correct way of doing things.

Comment: Given the focus $(h,k)$ and the directrix $y=mx+b$, the equation of the parabola is $${(y - mx - b)^2 \over m^2 +1} = (x - h)^2 + (y - k)^2.$$

Comment: If you put the focus at $(a,0)$ and the directrix at $x=-a$ then you get the equation $y^2 - 4ax = 0$ (or an equivalent equation; you didn't say what form your equation is in). The only way to get **that particular** equation for a parabola is if the focus is at $(a,0)$ and the directrix is at $x=-a$. On the other hand if you are looking for the equation of some other parabola then you cannot have the focus at $(a,0)$ and the directrix at $x=-a$. What is "the" equation you're looking for?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

EDIT: This got a downvote, which made me check to see what was off, there's an addition at the asterisk below.

If you did not know the focus or directrix, but you DO have a curve in a coordinate space, and you know it is a parabola, there are several options. I presume the axis is vertical, with upward opening.

1. Find the vertex $(p,q)$. Then $y+q=(x-p)^2$* *, if this is a $y=x^2$ form of a parabola. If it is wider or narrower, you need to determine a scalar, $m$ to account for that, most easily done by examining the value of the curve at $p+1$, to yield $y+q=m(x-p)^2$*. This is the only simple option if you have imaginary roots.
2. Identify where the parabola touches/crosses zero, these are the roots, and there are at most two distinct real roots. If one, $y=(x-r_1)^2$. If two, $y=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)$.
3. One or both of those methods will work for any parabola, and if it opens downward, just add a negative sign to the RHS. If you then wish to find the geometric focus and directrix, reverse the process below.

Start with a parabola with axis on the y-axis and vertex at the origin:

[image]

Then for any point $(x,y)$ on the parabola:

Since the distances from $(x,y)$ to the focus and directrix are the same, use Euclidean distance (i.e., Pythagorean theorem), but square both sides of the equality so you never deal with square roots

$\sqrt{(x-0)^2+(y-a)^2}=\sqrt{(x-x)^2+(y-(-a))^2}$

$(x-0)^2+(y-a)^2=(x-x)^2+(y-(-a))^2$

$(x-0)^2+(y-a)^2=(y+a)^2$

$x^2+y^2-2ay+a^2=y^2+2ay+a^2$

$x^2-2ay=2ay$

$x^2=4ay$

P.S. You will find this brief derivation in virtually any book on coordinate geometry, also in many calculus texts since parabolas are some of the simplest curves to examine.

Answer (score 2):

Parabola by definition is the locus of points equidistant from a given point and a given line.

To derive its equation assume a general line of the form ax+by+c=0 and a general point (h,k). Use the standard formulas for distance from a line and distance from a point and equate them.